# Problem updating the LOG4J library version

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j

I'm trying to update the LOG4J version of a project, but I'm always getting an error when I try to compile the project

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectCompany-ear</artifactId>
    <name>ProjectCompany-ear</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

<properties>
    <rootFolder>..${file.separator}..</rootFolder>
    <archive.dir>${project.build.directory}</archive.dir>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>ProjectCompany</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/application</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>

            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ProjectCompany-ejb-jar</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ProjectCompany</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/ProjectCompanyPortal</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ProjectCompany</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>jsqlparser</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.sephora.atg.webservices</groupId>
                        <artifactId>atgwsclient</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>axis</groupId>
                        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>APP-INF/lib</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectCompany-ejb-jar</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectCompanyCRMApp</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.bi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectCompanyBMWeb</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ProjectCompany.atg.webservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>atgwsclient</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Of all the suggestions. I found it more coherent to add this following code

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, I always get this error and I can't update the lib.
[image]

I even deleted this file and the error still persists

the project is using Java 6 and maven 2.3.2

Comment: @NathanHughes java 6, it has to be 2.3.1 LMAO

Comment: You clearly have network errors while downloading the artifact.

Comment: Looks like you are getting an html instead of pom.xml content.  This may happen if you are behind a proxy.